# can we pass images for which height!=width through our CNN for training in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

can we pass images for which height!=width through our CNN in Pytorch?

In CNN, I have convolution, batch-norm, max-pool, relu, and fully connected layers.

My network

```
self.conv_seqn = nn.Sequential(
nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=4, stride=4),
nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=4, stride=4),
)
self.fc_seqn = nn.Sequential(
nn.Linear(1843200, 256),
nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
nn.Linear(256, total_configs)
)
```

## my forward function

```
forward()
{
 x = self.conv_seqn(x)
 x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
 x = self.fc_seqn(x)
 return x
}
```

If input image of size 3840*1920*3 after applying conv_seqn() it should be of size [1, 128, 120, 60] but I getting the size of [1,128,120,120] (batch size =1 here)

any suggestion will be highly helpful.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your findings. `print(self.conv_seqn(torch.zeros(1, 3, 3840, 2160)).shape)` results in `torch.Size([1, 128, 120, 67])` which is the expected shape if you work through the output shape of each of the max pooling layers.

Comment: @jodag, thanks for the reply. I have made the changes to the post. Actually, the input image tensor size (1, 3, 3840, 1920) which must result in (1, 128, 60, 60) but for me its generating (1, 128, 120, 120). can anyone plz tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Torch does not require matching height and width. Have you tried to break the `Sequential` into discrete layers and then checked the size of the output at each step using `print`s/a debugger?  That will be the best way to see where the expected sizes first differs from your expectations.